# How can i pull single file (myfile.php) on server?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull

I make some changes in my locally file with php extension (myfile.php) and i want to pull my file into server. I already use this command :

- git commit yourfile.js

but i have an error like this "error: pathspec 'function.php' did not match any file(s) known to git."

I'll be glad for any help. Thanks .

Comment: Could you please elaborate your query? Actually not getting with things you mentioned here. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to push to git server or pull from git server? I don't know what you mean by "pull into server".

Comment: sorry, i mean push to git server

Comment: @Valendria You need to `@Olaia` in order to alert them to the above comment.

Comment: Git commit myfile.php

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
git add myfile.php
git commit -m"your message"
git push origin [branch to push]
```

This is what I understood from your question. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes. Thanks a lot. I am really beginer in this thing.